# How to fix list display selects correctly but retrieves data incorrectly

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to retrieve data when the item inside the ListBox(lstDisplay) is selected and display it into my textField.

Record shows in ListBox(lstDisplay),when I clicked on a single record, those record will display in the textfield, the problem is that it displays incorrectly

Please see screen shot [image: Screenshot]

Please see my code:

```
Private Sub lstDisplay_Change()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Row  
        If lstDisplay.Selected(i) Then
            Rows(i + 10).Select
            txtSearch.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
            txtLname.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
            txtFname.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3)
            cmbCourse.Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4)
            cmbYear.Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5)
        End If      
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Indexes start at 0, not 1. You're off by 1. ;)

Comment: Also, I hope this is not production data, otherwise I'd recommend exchanging the screenshot with something that only has "dummy" information it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counter of `lstDisplay` starts with `0` while the row counting of `Cells(row, column)` starts with `1`. Therfore you must use `i + 1` for the cells.

And actually I recommend to loop through the listbox instead of the cells

```
Private Sub lstDisplay_Change()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To lstDisplay.ListCount - 1  
        If lstDisplay.Selected(i) Then
            'Rows(i + 10).Select 'not needed
            txtSearch.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 1)
            txtLname.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 2)
            txtFname.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 3)
            cmbCourse.Value = Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 4)
            cmbYear.Value = Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 5)
        End If      
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @BuchiTyrone check my edit. This should be a way faster.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the listbox selection is 0-based, so changing the indexer to `i-1` should to the trick:

```
Private Sub lstDisplay_Change()
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 1 To Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Row
    If lstDisplay.Selected(i-1) Then
       Rows(i + 10).Select
       txtSearch.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
       txtLname.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
       txtFname.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3)
       cmbCourse.Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4)
       cmbYear.Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5)
     End If
   Next i
End Sub
```